# Turn this summation into Python code (int or float)

Tags: python, sum

I need to turn the following summation into Python code:
[This Summation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yi2VH.png)

the summation length N is known.

I'm struggling with the second summation
I need something like this

```
for i in range(N):
    (1 - (for j in range(N):
             sum(x[i][j]))**2
```

But the second for loop is obviously not going to work (Syntax Error)
How can I iterate over j within the first for loop?
The result needs to be saved in a variable

Thank you very much

Comment: I don't understand what you want to achieve with the `1 - for ...` which obviously not works as you point out yourself. Do you want to subtract the result from 1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    sum = 0
    for i in range(N):
        sum_inside = 0
        for j in range(N):
            sum_inside += x[i][j]
        sum += (1 - sum_inside)**2
```

Answer (score 3):

`sum` can take a generator expression, so you can make this a pretty clean one-liner with:

```
total = sum((1 - sum(x[i][j] for j in range(N)))**2 for i in range(N))
```

If `N` is such that you are actually summing all the elements (array is square and N == number of rows/columns) in the array you can do away with the ranges and just use:

```
sum((1 - sum(n for n in row))**2  for row in x)
```

which you can also do in numpy with something like:

```
x = np.array(x)
np.sum((1 - np.sum(x, axis=1))**2)
```

or if `N` is to take a slice of the matrix:

```
a = np.array(x)
N = 2
np.sum((1 - np.sum(a[0:N, 0:N], axis=1))**2)
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope you aren't asking stack overflow to do your homework!

The summation is a simple nested comprehension:

```
sum(1 - sum(x[i,j] for j in range(1, N+1)) ** 2 for i in range(1, N+1))
```

Don't take my word for it though; it's a good idea to check the results. Here I am using x as a tuple-keyed dict.

Be aware that the image ranges from 1 to N, not from 0 to N-1.  If x is a 2d array, then that would be okay if you are adjusting for zero-indexing.

@MarkMeyer has a more comprehensive answer than this one.
Regarding vectors / multi-dimensional arrays, we have recently decided it's a little more pythonic to represent them as tuple-keyed dicts instead of nested lists.  For instance, with x above, we define it as follows:

```
x = {(i,j): fn(i,j) for j in range(1, N) for i in range(1, N)}
```

The major advantage is that there is no preference of index, and we are able to use filter/map for most functions.

[image: Simple summation]

Comment: I would expect `x` to be vector of some sort not a function with this notation.

Comment: @MarkMeyer, yes it's true. But even with vectors, there's a difference between 0..n and 1..n+1, no? Likewise, a vector can always be interchanged with a function.. It's a preference thing, I guess..

Comment: Sure, that's fair enough @Konchog.

Comment: @MarkMeyer, I decided you were right in this example - but changed it to a tuple-keyed dict (our current preference for this sort of structure).

Answer (score -1):

I think this is may be a solution for your problem. Still x[i][j] is confusing.

```
N=int(input("Enter the value of N "))
Sum=0
for i in range(N):
    for j in range(N):
        Sum =Sum+( 1 - (sum(x[i][j]))**2)
print(Sum)
```